# Swift: accessing struct variables with a String

Tags: swift, struct

I am looking for a better way to access the variables of a struct. A json query fills an array of this struct:

```
    struct AnimalInfo: Codable {
        var English: String
        var French: String
        var Spanish: String
    }
```

An example:

```
    let theDog = AnimalInfo(English: "Dog", French: "Chien", Spanish: "Perro")
```

The languages are in an array, the current one is always changing. I keep track with a pointer:

```
    let languageListArray = ["English", "French", "Spanish"]
    let currentLanguage = languageListArray[2]
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve the value from the struct with this information, something along the lines of:

```
    let myString = theDog.currentLanguage // = "Perro"
```

.. but of course that is not possible. The best I've come up with so far is a switch:

```
    switch currentLanguage {
        case "English":
            return theDog.English
        case "French":
            return theDog.French
        case "Spanish":
            return theDog.Spanish
    }
```

But this is ugly, and doesn't scale well with many languages! Anyone have a better way?

Comment: Could you make a dictionary and make the keys the languages and the values the translation? Then for the initializer you would just get a dictionary rather than multiple parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but of course that is not possible

Oh, it is possible if you use **key paths**

```
struct AnimalInfo: Codable {
    let english: String
    let french: String
    let spanish: String
}

let theDog = AnimalInfo(english: "Dog", french: "Chien", spanish: "Perro")

let languageListArray : [KeyPath<AnimalInfo,String>] = [\.english, \.french, \.spanish]

let currentLanguage = languageListArray[2]

let myString = theDog[keyPath: currentLanguage] // = "Perro"
```

Comment: Nice use of keyPaths, but is this what the question is getting at?  Unless I'm misreading, it still requires the creation of the array which has the same manual/scaling problems of the OP's switch statement.  I think the question was asking for a dot syntax approach without having to explicitly define the internal representation.

Comment: @flanker I think that key path subscription is pretty close to dot notation. Accessing properties with strings cannot be recommended.

Comment: agree with your logic and use of keypaths ... and not using strings!  Just not sure it answers the OP, esp the bit referring to it becoming ugly with a long list of languages as creating the language array would suffer in a similar way. Not that I have a better solution! :)

Comment: @vadian Thank you, I was finding the docs on KeyPath sparse, and wasn't sure if I could use it. @ flanker, it's true it's not exactly what I was asking for, but it is much better than what I was using before!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible without keyPaths too

```
protocol Translated {
    var english: String { get }
    var french: String { get }
    var spanish: String { get }
}

struct Animal: Codable, Translated {
    let english: String
    let french: String
    let spanish: String
}

let english: (Translated) -> String = { $0.english }
// or you can write that as a key path \.english 
let french: (Translated) -> String = { $0.french }
let spanish: (Translated) -> String = { $0.spanish }


let theDog = Animal(english: "Dog", french: "Chien", spanish: "Perro")

english(theDog) // Dog

french(theDog) // Chien

var currentLanguage: (Translated) -> String = english

currentLanguage(theDog) // Dog

currentLanguage = french

currentLanguage(theDog) // Chien
```

If you want your dot syntax then:

```
extension Translated {
    var inCurrentLanguage: String { currentLanguage(self) }
}

theDog.inCurrentLanguage // Chien
```

You can indeed use key paths to specify your function without having to name it, e.g.

```
// no need to define/name these functions
// let spanish: (Translated) -> String = { $0.spanish }

currentLanguage = \.spanish

theDog.inCurrentLanguage // Perro
```

Comment: Also very nice variation! Thanks, @Shadowrun